# How do I do this in WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

I have this project I like to use WPF ListView

1. it will look like a PropertyGrid in Winform. I already found some implementation on the web, which is the best?
2. from [what I learn](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-3-in-place-edit), I can only binding a class from DependencyObject, is it possible to binding a generic List or Dictionary, myClass will include name, value, type (string, double, bool, lookup list, ...). Once I binding it, it will add relate template, e.g. for lookup list, it will add combobox in celltemplate.
3. further, I like to have everything in a configuration file. e.g. I have this configuration:

   Name1, Value1, string
   Name2, Value2, bool
   Name3, Value3, lookup, N3_option1, N3_option2, N3_option3, ...

   my code will read configuration file first, then from there, I read Name1/Name2/Name3 from database, show them in my ListView, from Name3, you pick value from (N3_option1, N3_option2, N3_option3, ...).

   If you can point me the right direction, I will appreciate it so much.

**Update**: 
here is 3 examples I'm looking at:

[DataTemplates in Action: Building a simple PropertyGrid](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html), [WPF PropertyGrid - MVVM techniques](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PropertyGridMVVM.aspx), and [WPF Property Grid](http://wpg.codeplex.com/).

"WPF Property Grid" is too complicate for a beginner like me. Personally, I more like "DataTemplates in Action: Building a simple PropertyGrid".

it also have code to select DataTemplate depend on DataType of each class property: bool use BooleanDataTemplate which is a checkbox; Enum use EnumDataTemplate which is a combobox.

I also like go a little further, add custom type: lookup, which will show as dropdown list, but the value list come from database. e.g.

property name: car manufacturere, value come from "SELECT LOOKUP_VALUE FROM LOOKUP WHERE LOOKUP_KEY = 'CAR_MFG'", which will return a list like: Toyota, Ford, Nissan, Honda, VW, BMW, ...

If I have > 1 lookup properties, how I can speciafy them? LookupDataTemplate1, LookupDataTemplate2, ..., then how to specify them in XAML Resources. and all DataTemplate are pre-defined in XAML, how I can do it in this case.

similar to EnumToListConverter, How I can create LookupmToListConverter1,  LookupmToListConverter2?

Answer (score 1):

1) I am unsure what the question here is.  You can do it with a ListView, its just a matter if it fits your data well.  It sounds reasonable given what you wrote.

2) You can make a `DependencyProperty` that is a List or Dictionary and bind to it that way.  You can also use the `ObservableCollection<T>` class (basically a list that notifies when its state changes) and bind to it.  You can also use any other class that uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` and bind to that.  Adding the combobox through the template sounds appropriate.

3)It sounds like you you need a class to use to read from your configuration and then display it to the list view.  These would be your view model.  You could make a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this.  You'd have three fields 1)Name 2) Value, 3)Potential Values.  Name and value both would be strings.  I'm assuming Name would be a one way binding and Value would be on a two way binding on the combobox whose items are bound to the Potential Values.  You then would create an `ObservableCollection<T>` of these objects and bind your `ListView` to that.  The serializing and deserialzing to this collection should be relatively straightforward.